# How to change the .pst default location in outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

how can i change the data file location in outlook 2013 for yahoo mail. i have configured the mail account which is working fine. But i already have a PST file in a separate location, and i want my yahoo mails should use that particular PST file.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are asking two questions.
1: how to move a pst file, (shut down outlook, move it, and under account settings select it in the new location)
and
2: how to change the default location for new pst files, which involves a registry edit
https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/config/to-move-an-outlook-personal-folders-pst-file/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.